# Use m2doc outside of eclipse

Tags: m2doc

I'm evaluation the options to generate templated OOXML documents and found M2Doc approach.

I would like to know if it's possible to use M2Doc outside eclipse (like with a CLI call to some jar) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use M2Doc in standalone (outside Eclipse). You can use the documentation to use M2Doc [programmatically](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#using-m2doc-programmatically). Binaries are only distributed in a P2 repository, but you can convert it to maven using [CBI/aggregator](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CBI/aggregator#Creating_a_Maven-conformant_p2_repo).

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues/519) to create a maven compatible repository. If you make the aggregator model on your side, feel free to attach it to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've read this part of the documentation but I have to admit that I don't know how to use it (disclaimer: I don't have a lot of java experience). Do you know if there is a full "hello world" / tuto example out there ?

Comment: You can check the test suite [class](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/tests/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.tests/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/tests/AbstractTemplatesTestSuite.java) and its implementation for a working standalone [example](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/tests/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.tests/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/tests/QueryTests.java).